# Style buttons inside mat-menu angular 2+

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, styles

I want to somehow style my mat-menu to work a little bit like a modal( dialog ).
However styling is quite a challange for me, Could you please advise how to move buttons (save and reset)
to the right and make a space between them ? I ve tried to apply styles to them however they' re not working.

I have tried to create my own css class and apply it to html button however nothing happens - Please look stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtscpl?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to align your buttons to the right and add a gap you can easily add some flex styles around your buttons:

Example:

```
    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; gap: 10px; flex-direction: row; place-content: flex-end;">
      ...
    </div>
```

You can even add these styles to the mat-toolbar-row.

Comment: nice, it was so simple solution, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the style of a library.

If the library makes updates on the code, you have to follow through. Moreover, it breaks the purpose of implementing the library : it's called Angular Material because it implements Material Design. If you change it, what's the point of using the library ?

Instead, use the CDK. [The menu is part of it](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/overview) and offers the exact same feature, minus the CSS.

Start from there, it should be easier to work with.

Comment: I'm trying to import that module{ CdkMenuModule } from '@angular/cdk/menu';
however Im getting an error Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/menu' even after installing npm install --save @angular/cdk, could you please advise?